# Unable to animate sprite renderer

Tags: unity

[image]

Why am I unable to add any of the sprite renderer's properties? How can I do it? On all the other properties like transform and so on, when I open them I have a + indicator in the right if I want to add any.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to realize the plus signs are just out of view ;) Not sure why a double click doesn't just add it though.

Comment: Just when you think you've seen it all... Wow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the bottom scroll bar to the right to reveal the plus signs